# Efficient transformation of a lists of x/y coordinates to a data frame in R

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe

I have a list of length 30,000 with data frames in it that have a x and y column. The data frame is sparse, so not each value of x exists. All x values are between 1 and 200.

I want to convert this list to a single data frame which has for each possible x value a column and each row should represent all y values of a list entry (if a x value does not exist, the entry should be 0). I have a solution which works (see below) but it's very, very slow and I think there must be a faster (and probably also more elegant way) to do so.

My current solution (which is slow) is:

```
dat <- matrix(numeric(0), 30000, 200) 
for(i in seq(along=whaledatas)) {
    for(j in row.names(whaledatas[[i]]))
        dat[i, whaledatas[[i]][j,"x"]] <- whaledatas[[i]][j,"y"]
}

dfData <- data.frame(dat, files$label)
dfData[is.na(dfData)] <- 0
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you can use the idiom `do.call(rbind, whaledatas`) to convert a `list` of `data.frames` into a single `data.frame`.

Comment: When you say the values are between 1 and 200, are these integer values only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an answer that takes reasonable amount of time:

```
# function to create dummy data
my_sampler <- function(idx) {
    x <- sample(200, sample(50:100, 1))
    y <- sample(length(x))
    data.frame(x,y)
}

# create list of 30000 data.frames
in.d <- lapply(1:30000, function(x) my_sampler(x))
```

**Solution:** Using `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
system.time(out.d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(in.d, function(x) {
    setattr(x, 'class', c("data.table", "data.frame")) # mnel's suggestion
    setkey(x, "x")
    x[J(1:200)]$y
})))

#   user  system elapsed 
# 47.111   0.343  51.283 

> dim(out.d)
# [1] 30000   200

# final step: replace NA with 0
out.d[is.na(out.d)] <- 0
```

**Edit:** As @regetz shows, assigning final matrix and then replacing selected entries where x occurs with y-values is clever! A small variation of @regetz's solution:

```
m <- matrix(0.0, nrow=30000, ncol=200)
system.time(for( i in 1:nrow(m)) {
    m[i, in.d[[i]][["x"]]] <- in.d[[i]][["y"]]
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.496   0.003   1.511
```

This seems to be even faster than @regetz's (shown below):

```
> system.time(dat <- datify(in.d, xmax=200))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.966   0.015   2.993
```

Comment: @mnel, Thanks for `setattr`. I've edited the code. Although I don't see performance difference (51 seconds).

Comment: And I use `do.call(rbind, ..)` because I'm returning a vector. `rbindlist` expects data.frame/data.table/list. And I do it this way because I'd like to get the matrix of 30000*200 directly. By doing `rbindlist` I end up with a `data.table` (of two columns, x and y) from which I've to create a matrix again. There's no performance gain. to create the data.table alone, it takes 51 seconds.

Comment: `setattr` avoids a copy, this is a good thing, it is also instaneous, so will scale with a larger data. I'm not convinced I really understand the question, and perhaps `rbindlist --> reshape to wide is what the OP is after.

Comment: @mnel, the problem is that you can *not* directly `rbind` (or `rbindlist`). The OP has 30000 data.frames of two columns x and y. x ranges from 1 to 200, but not all data.frames have all 200 values. So, we've to fill y = 0 for missing values of x and return a 30000 * 200 output. I can't think of a direct method or efficient method *after rbind-ing`. Hence, I get the NA's filled first and then call rbind on the vector which are all of length 200.

Comment: I must say, I can't see how we get to 200 columns from this single column, I've got so say the wording of the question is baffling to me, without an example of the input and expected output. I'm still not convinced that x will be integer, and that bothers me.

Comment: Thank all of you! I took your matrix variation, it's clean, short and fast. It makes my data analysis work so much smoother!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `data.table` solution , something like this :

```
whaledatas <- lapply(1:30000,function(x)data.frame(x=1:200,y=1:200))
library(data.table)
dtt <- rbindlist(whaledatas)
```

Comment: and what about the missing values? he expects a 30000 * 200 data.frame/matrix.

Comment: @Arun i have no idea how `rbindList` will behave with NA values. I choose it because it is fast comparing to `do.call` for example.

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a small example of a list of data frames:

```
# create some sample data
whaledatas <- list(
    data.frame(x=1:3, y=11:13),
    data.frame(x=6:10, y=16:20)
)
```

I think this does the same thing as the `for` loop in the original question?

```
# combine into single data frame
whaledatas.all <- do.call("rbind", whaledatas)

# change this to 200! kept small here for illustration...
XMAX <- 10

# create output matrix
dat <- matrix(0.0, length(whaledatas), XMAX)

# create index vector for dat rows
i <- rep(1:length(whaledatas), sapply(whaledatas, nrow))

# populate dat
dat[cbind(i, whaledatas.all[["x"]])] <- whaledatas.all[["y"]]
```

**Edit**

The `rbind` gets horrendously slow as the number of the inputs increases. This version (wrapped in a function for convenience) avoids it, and runs much faster:

```
datify <- function(x, xmax=200) {
    dat <- matrix(0.0, length(x), xmax)
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
        this.df <- x[[i]]
        coords <- cbind(rep(i, nrow(this.df)), this.df[["x"]])
        dat[coords] <- this.df[["y"]]
    }
    dat
}
```

Note that we started with all zeros in `dat`, so no need to fix that after the fact...

```
> datify(whaledatas, xmax=10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   11   12   13    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0   16   17   18   19    20
```

Timing on 30k-length list of sample data frames, generated using Arun's `my_sampler` function:

```
set.seed(99)
in.d <- lapply(1:30000, function(x) my_sampler(x))
system.time(dat <- datify(in.d, xmax=200))
##   user  system elapsed 
##  1.317   0.011   1.328
```

Comment: FWIW, this `datify` function runs in <2 seconds for me on a list of 30k sample data frames, using Arun's very helpful my_sampler function

Comment: would you mind running a `system.time(.)` your code on 30000 data.frames? you can use the function from my code to create one, if you wish.

Comment: @Arun: thanks for the suggestion (and function). i added timings to my answer.

Comment: can you run my edited solution on your system and benchmark similarly in your post, please? The `for` solution.

Comment: @Arun: yep, your variant runs in ~0.8 sec rather than 1.3 sec for mine. more concise code, too! nice...